# Using node.js functions in gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm looking to integrate more-css(https://github.com/army8735/more) into my gulp workflow. I've tried several different options. I'm not sure what the syntax to include a function of this type would be. Could someone clarify?

```
gulp.task('more-css', function () {
  var moreCss = require('more-css');

  return gulp.src('./in')
    .pipe(moreCss.compress('paint.css', true))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./out'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pradyumna's answer is not correct; gulp plugins are basically transform streams. It's not enough to use the node API directly, you have to wrap it in some streaming logic. Having had a brief look around on npm, there isn't a gulp plugin that you can use for `more-css`, so I made one. Install with:

```
npm install gulp-more-css --save-dev
```

And a code example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var moreCSS = require('gulp-more-css');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('./in')
        .pipe(moreCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./out'));
});
```

https://github.com/ben-eb/gulp-more-css

Answer (score 0):

```
 var moreCss=require('more-css');
 gulp.task('build', function(){
 var cssFile='paint.css';//path to paint.css
 gulp.src(cssFile)
 .pipe(moreCss.compress(gulp.src(cssFile), true))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./out'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I try that method I get this error: TypeError: Object TypeError: Object #<DestroyableTransform> has no method 'indexOf' has no method 'on'
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (/Users/djfrsn/vivy/Projects/rag/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:516:8)

I tried various syntax changes but nothing came of it.

Comment: Thanks, Swain. This looks promising. I'll take a look soon. My work on my gulpfile has halted for the moment...after I take care of this project I'll come back with my findings.